# How to receive the encoded byte array in rest webservice and decode it and save as image in java

Tags: java, ajax, jakarta-ee, resteasy

I am trying to get encoded byte of image into base64 format and sending to rest webservice. Inside the service i want to decode it and convert it back to image and want to save the image in my local path. Its fails during decoding. I dont know whether the logic is correct. Need some guidance

```
    @POST
    @Path("/imageupload")
    @Produces("text/html")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
     public String execute(@FormDataParam("image") String inputfile) throws Exception
    {

            System.out.println("entered into service");
        BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        ByteBuffer img=decoder.decodeBufferToByteBuffer(inputfile); 
        System.out.println();
            File outputfile = new File("D:\\TEST\\test.png");
                ImageIO.write(img, "png", outputfile);
```

The logic is:

```
Step 1: get the byte array as string inside the service.
Step 2: decode it 
Step 3: write the byte into file with png format
```

Comment: What is the problem with decoding? Stacktrace?

Comment: @VasylKeretsman I dont know i am going in right path.. first the above steps are correct ???

Comment: Is your code compiling at all?

Comment: yeah its get compiled but i am getting blank image in local path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you get correctly encoded image and you are sure it is png, I would do it this way.

```
BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
byte[] decodedImageBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(inputfile); 
final FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\TEST\\test.png"));
out.write(decodedImageBytes);
out.close();
```

P.S. Make sure you receive the image as encoded string.